# invalid DWARF generated by the compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, dwarf

> warning: invalid DWARF generated by the compiler: DIE 0x000629bb has
>   multiple AT_decl_line attributes in
>   '/Code/test/Mac1.7to1.8Test/build/Mac1.7to1.8Test.build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OgreFramework.o'.

I'm getting this in XCode 3.2.6 building a C++ project and as a newbie on Mac I never even *heard* of Dwarf! What is this warning about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is debugging information ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF)). I'd say this is either error in compiler itself or mismatched compiler and linker version.

[This known and fixed bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45171) is probably the cause. See if you can get updated compiler.